# Titanium - Titanium Studio doesn't use my images

Tags: image, titanium

I'm trying to make an app with Titanium Studio 3.1.0.201304151600, I already made some apps and they were all fine, but now, every time if i try to make a new app, it doesn't use any of my images, not even my icon etc. I looked everywhere on the internet but I couldn't find anything about it. Sorry if this is already asked by someone but I'm really desperate.

Comment: Are the old apps still showing the images if you do a project clean and recompile them?  If not, I would probably consider removing Titanium Studio and re-installing it.

Comment: Okay I will try reinstalling

Comment: @Klass, did re-installing help?